# Display a wide data table in Android: it's worth using a WebView?

Tags: android, html, listview, webview, scrollview

I need to display a technical data table in Android, full of numbers and with many columns. The table must be wider than the display, i.e. it should scroll both vertically (to scroll rows) and horizontally (to scroll columns).

My first though was to use a standard `ListView` with items consisting of `TextView` arranged horizontally, make it wider than the screen using a fixed width, and put it in a `HorizontalScrollView`.

But then I tried loading a huge HTML table into a `WebView`, styled with a fixed width and inside a `overflow: scroll` container, and it worked flawlessly and without any noticeable performance issue. **Why not?** Do you see any drawback? UX is very limited, and I think I can easily manage it using Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to you. There is no serious restrictions. Maybe, you should test these:

1) Some vendors make their own implementations of WebView;

2) Webview before/after android 4.4 (was updated to chromium);

3) Security reasons (from off. docs):

> Caution: Using addJavascriptInterface() allows JavaScript to control your Android application. This can be a very useful feature or a dangerous security issue. When the HTML in the WebView is untrustworthy (for example, part or all of the HTML is provided by an unknown person or process), then an attacker can include HTML that executes your client-side code and possibly any code of the attacker's choosing. As such, you should not use addJavascriptInterface() unless you wrote all of the HTML and JavaScript that appears in your WebView. You should also not allow the user to navigate to other web pages that are not your own, within your WebView (instead, allow the user's default browser application to open foreign links—by default, the user's web browser opens all URL links, so be careful only if you handle page navigation as described in the following section).

Also, i suggest to make it native, if you need to do serious operations to data from table.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check 1) and 2). I'm not worried for 3) because the HTML will be generated by the application itself, and it'll not include content from any untrusted sources.